# Docker Images - What are these layers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am looking at this image and it seems the layers are redundant and these redundant layers ended up in the image ? If they are , how they ended up in the image leading to large amount of space ?
How could i strip these layers ?

https://microbadger.com/images/openkbs/docker-spark-bde2020-zeppelin:latest

[image]

Comment: Those are not layers, those are different versions of the same image, as it has evolved over time. One can see the layer of each image by clicking the `+` on the right.

Comment: hmm, does it mean the image is built keeping the old versions intact ?

Comment: Yes, it does (filling up the message since it was two characters too short).

Comment: sorry, would you mind elaborating what do you mean "it was two characters too short"

Comment: A comment must have at least 15 characters so you can post it. Mine was two characters too short, thus i filled it up with some text :)

Comment: i see, got it , stockoverflow thing :-) . BTW, what options do i have now ? create my own custom image or is it possible to strip off the image to have the old versions removed ?

Comment: Please add it as a solution, I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "strip off the old images". if you need one specific version of the image, pull that image and that's that.

Comment: sorry, I mean the image in question retaining old versions of the same image , is it possible to strip off the old versions and just keep the latest version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220696/discussion-between-nag-and-turing85).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing are not layers, but images that were pushed to the same registry. Basically, those are the different versions of one image.

In a repository, each image is accessible through an unique ID, its SHA value. Furthermore, one can tag images with convenient names, e.g. `V1.0` or `latest`. These tags are not fixed, however. When an image is pushed with a tag that is already assigned to another image, the old image loses the tag and the new image gains it. Thus, a tag can move from one image to another. [The tag `latest` is no exception](https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375). It has, however, one special property: the tag is always assigned to the most recently pushed version of an image.

The person/owner of the registry has pushed new versions of the image and not tagged the old versions. Thus, all old versions show up as "untagged".

If we pull a specific image, we will receive this image and this image only, not the complete registry.